# Downloading files from an SFTP server using JSch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am using jsch to download files from server, my code below.

```
public static void downloadFile(TpcCredentialsDTO dto) {
        logger.trace("Entering downloadFile() method");
        
    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    boolean success = false;
    
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(dto.getUsername(), dto.getHost(),
                dto.getPort());
        session.setPassword(dto.getPassword());

        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect();
        logger.info("Connected to " + dto.getHost() + ".");
        
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        
        List<String> filesToDownload = getFilesToDownload(dto,channelSftp);
        
        if (!filesToDownload.isEmpty()) {
            for (String fileDownloadName : filesToDownload) {
                success = false;
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                    "C:\Download\BLT_03112012");
                
                channelSftp.get("BLT_03112012",output);
                success = true;
                if (success)
                    logger.info(ServerConstants.DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS_MSG
                                    + fileDownloadName);
                output.close();
            }

        }else {
            logger.info(ServerConstants.NO_FILES_TO_DOWNLOAD
                    + ServerUtils.getDateTime());
            success = true;
        }
        
    } catch (JSchException ex) {
        logger.error( ServerConstants.SFTP_REFUSED_CONNECTION, ex);
    } catch (SftpException ex) {
        logger.error(ServerConstants.FILE_DOWNLOAD_FAILED, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error(ServerConstants.FILE_NOT_FOUND, ex);
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ServerConstants.ERROR, ex);
    }finally {
        if (channelSftp.isConnected()) {
            try {
                session.disconnect();
                channel.disconnect();
                channelSftp.quit();
                logger.info( ServerConstants.FTP_DISCONNECT);
            } catch (Exception ioe) {
                logger.error(ServerConstants.FTP_NOT_DISCONNECT, ioe);
            }
        }
    }
    logger.trace("Exiting downloadFile() method");
}
```

The line `sftpChannel.get(filename, outputstream)` is throwing an error.

> ```
>   2: File not found
>       at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2629)
>       at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._get(ChannelSftp.java:977)
>       at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:946)
>       at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:924)
>       at za.co.tpc.sftpserver.SftpConnection.downloadFile(SftpConnection.java:72)
>       at za.co.tpc.server.execute.FtpMtn.main(FtpMtn.java:44)
> ```

The same code does download Text Document file types but fails for 'File' filetype

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using paths instead of stream:

```
String destPath = "filename.txt";        

if (!filesToDownload.isEmpty()) {
    for (String fileDownloadName : filesToDownload) {
        success = false;
        sftpChannel.get(fileDownloadName , destPath);
```

If you wanna use file and streams check this example:
http://kodehelp.com/java-program-for-downloading-file-from-sftp-server/

Answer (score 7):

Please find in the below code sample comprising the file **upload** and **download** functionalities. Please pull the relevant details from properties files where ever string marked in **lt;**sftp.user.name**gt;**. I am deleting the file once the file is downloaded you can have it as per your requirement.

The **event** and **locale** parameters what I have added as part of download functionality is to filter the file(s); you can pass parameters as par you need.

Have placed a check to set proxy which can be used on need basis.

```
package com.util;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ProxyHTTP;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 *
 * @author Dinesh.Lomte
 */
public class SftpUtil {

    /**
     * 
     * @param fileName
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void upload(String fileName)
    throws Exception {

        String method = "upload(String fileName)";
        Session session = null;
        Channel channel = null;
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
        try {
            // Creating and instantiating the jsch specific instance
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            // Fetching and setting the parameters like: user name, host and port 
            // from the properties file
            session = jsch.getSession("<sftp.user.name>",
                    "<sftp.host>",
                    Integer.valueOf("<sftp.port>"));
            // Fetching and setting the password as configured in properties files
            session.setPassword("<sftp.user.password>");
            // Setting the configuration specific properties
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);            
            // Validating if proxy is enabled to access the sftp
            isSftpProxyEnabled(session);
            // Execution start time
            long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
            System.out.println("Connecting to the sftp...");
            // Connecting to the sftp 
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected to the sftp.");            
            // Execution end time
            long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Connected to SFTP in : " + (lEndTime - lStartTime));
            // Setting the channel type as sftp
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            // Establishing the connection
            channel.connect();
            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            // Setting the folder location of the external system as configured
            channelSftp.cd("<sftp.output.folder.url>");
            // Creating the file instance
            File file = new File(fileName);
            // Creating an fileInputStream instance
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            // Transfering the file from it source to destination location via sftp
            channelSftp.put(fileInputStream, file.getName());
            // Closing the fileInputStream instance
            fileInputStream.close();
            // De-allocating the fileInputStream instance memory by assigning null
            fileInputStream = null;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw exception;
        } finally {
            // Validating if channel sftp is not null to exit
            if (channelSftp != null) {
                channelSftp.exit();
            }
            // Validating if channel is not null to disconnect
            if (channel != null) {
                channel.disconnect();
            }
            // Validating if session instance is not null to disconnect
            if (session != null) {
                session.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param session 
     */
    private static void isSftpProxyEnabled(Session session) {
        // Fetching the sftp proxy flag set as part of the properties file
        boolean isSftpProxyEnabled = Boolean.valueOf("<sftp.proxy.enable>");
        // Validating if proxy is enabled to access the sftp
        if (isSftpProxyEnabled) {
            // Setting host and port of the proxy to access the SFTP
            session.setProxy(new ProxyHTTP("<sftp.proxy.host>", 
                    Integer.valueOf("<sftp.proxy.port>");
        }
        System.out.println("Proxy status: " + isSftpProxyEnabled);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param folder
     * @param event
     * @param locale
     */
    public static void download(String folder, String event, String locale) {

        String method = "download(String folder, String event, String locale)";
        Session session = null;
        Channel channel = null;
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
        try {
            // Creating and instantiating the jsch specific instance
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            // Fetching and setting the parameters like: user name, host and port 
            // from the properties file
            session = jsch.getSession("<sftp.user.name>",
                    "<sftp.host>",
                    Integer.valueOf("<sftp.port>"));
            // Fetching and setting the password as configured in properties files
            session.setPassword("<sftp.user.password>");
            // Setting the configuration specific properties
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);            
            // Validating if proxy is enabled to access the sftp
            isSftpProxyEnabled(session);
            // Execution start time
            long lStartTime = new Date().getTime();
            System.out.println("Connecting to the sftp...");
            // Connecting to the sftp 
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected to the sftp.");            
            // Execution end time
            long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Connected to SFTP in : " + (lEndTime - lStartTime));
            // Setting the channel type as sftp
            channel = session.openChannel(SFTP);
            // Establishing the connection
            channel.connect();
            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            try {
                // Setting the folder location of the external system as configured 
                // to download the file from
                channelSftp.cd("<sftp.input.folder.url>");
            } catch (SftpException sftpException) {
                System.out.println("Failed to change the directory in sftp.");                
            }
            // Listing all the .csv file(s) specific to the source system, event type (download) and locale code
            Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> lsEntries = channelSftp.ls(
                    new StringBuilder("*").append("<sys.code>").append("*").append(event)
                    .append("*").append(locale).append("*").append(".csv").toString());
            // Validating if files exist to process the request further
            if (lsEntries.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No file exist in the specified sftp folder location.");
            }
            // Iterating the list of entries to download the file(s) from the sftp 
            for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : lsEntries) {
                try {
                    // Downloading the specified file from the sftp to the specified folder path
                    channelSftp.get(entry.getFilename(), new StringBuilder(folder)
                            .append(File.separator).append(entry.getFilename()).toString());
                } catch (SftpException sftpException) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to download the file the sftp folder location.");                    
                }                
            }
            // Iterating the list of entries to delete the file(s) from the sftp 
            for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : lsEntries) {
                try {
                    // Deleting the specified file from the sftp
                    channelSftp.rm(entry.getFilename());
                } catch (SftpException sftpException) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to delete the file from the sftp folder location.");                    
                }                
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("Failed to download the file(s) from SFTP.");            
        } finally {
            // Validating if channel sftp is not null to exit
            if (channelSftp != null) {
                channelSftp.exit();
            }
            // Validating if channel is not null to disconnect
            if (channel != null) {
                channel.disconnect();
            }
            // Validating if session instance is not null to disconnect
            if (session != null) {
                session.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed in this way:

```
Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> files = sftp.ls(remotePath);
String remotePath = properties.getFtpPath();
Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> files = sftp.ls(remotePath);

for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : files) {

    InputStream stream = sftp.get(remotePath + "/" + entry.getFilename());
    // Your business code here

}
```

Where remotePath is the remote SFTP folder name.