# Unable to download the file from unix to windows using sftp connection

Tags: java

My requirement is to get the file from remote machine(Unix) to local machine(Unix/windows). When I run the code in Unix, I am able to download the file from Unix(remote) to Unix(local) but when I run the code Windows, I am not able to get the file from Unix(remote) to Windows(local), I see error message as "Message: 4"
for the line 
channel.get(folderPath + "/" + fileNameFound, localFolder);

why I see issue in windows not in UNIX.

Comment: Share your code for more clarity.

Comment: I added my code in the description. Kindly check.

Comment: Find below the old reference.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680057/downloading-files-from-an-sftp-server-using-jsch

Answer (score 0):

If I read this code correctly:

```
channel.get(folderPath + "/" + fileNameFound, localFolder);
```

then you are building a file path there. File paths are different on Unix and Windows systems.
Have you tried using Java's built-in `Path` class to resolve the file paths?

Also: providing a larger code snippet would make it easier to figure out the problem ;)

Comment: I added my code in the description. Thanks for looking into it.
I am taking care of paths based on environments(UNIX and windows).